# Which partition looks least important? I need a spare partition for Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, partitioning, oem

[image: http://imgur.com/YgYc9Oo]

I have been wanting to install Ubuntu for a while, but, I've ran into the "too many partitions" problem, but I am not sure which to make into extended ones, and which not to.

Sorry for low quality question by the way.

Comment: Personally I'd remove the recovery partition and the OEM partition, but only if additional recovery media can be created in its place.

Comment: It came with additional recovery media, and have been using said media to recover Windows for a while. It's a basic Windows Install Disc and a disc with drivers and bloatware on it, though if I ever wanted to recreate the recovery partition, how would I do that?

Comment: To recreate the recovery partitions I would restore the computer using your recovery discs. it will format the hard drive and reinstate it back to factory settings. The way I see it, if the hard drive failed, you'd be without those partitions to recover anyway, but that's my personal approach.

Comment: Well true. It's a bold move, and I'll probably back up the files on the recovery partitiion again just in case, but still, It's not my main computer anymore xD

Comment: Is `D:\ ` your Recovery partition or is **Recover** just a name for a normal drive? Because I wonder why would a Recovery Partition which should be flagged hidden is enabled with a drive letter [D:] here.

Comment: `if I ever wanted to recreate the recovery partition, how would I do that?` -- I or others can help  but posting it here would deviate from the original question's context.

Comment: D:\ Recover was the name for my Recovery Partition, MEDION (Manifacturer) decided not to hide it, probably because it also contained files for drivers and bloatware, along with the actually recovery stuff

And If I ever will need to recreate it, I'll create a new post, I didn't think about this showing up in search results :P